# This seems simple but, how do i prove A isn't in C?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\in B$ and $B\in C$, Is it posible to prove $A$ isn't in $C$?

Sorry for simplistic exercise, but been wondering this for days now...

The question in the book says:
Can you deduce that $A\in C$ ?

but feels hollow to answer just "no".

Comment: If $A\in B\subset C$ then $B\in \mathscr P(C)$ and $A\notin C$ but $\{A\}\in \mathscr P(C)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ can be in $C$ or can not be in $C$ :

Take $A$, $B = \{A\}$ and $C = \{A, \{A\}\}$, then $A\in C$

Take $A$, $B = \{A\}$ and $C=\{\{A\}\}$ then $A\not\in C$

Comment: I can't believe i didn't thought of adding a counterexample, not it doens't feel hollow. Thannks for attention.

Comment: Hi @Tryss, but isn't $\{\{A\}\} = A$?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, the L.H.S. is an *element* in that set, I think... @Tryss

Comment: @User001 : No, even worse ! it's $\{A\}$ that is an element in that set (and $A$ is an element of an element of this set :p)